Keyboard shortcut to switch tabs on pycharm mac?
Up until now I've been using my mouse to switch between tabs in pycharm on my mac; as you probably already know, this is very inefficient.
Keyboard shortcut to switch tab on pycharm mac?

From the Pycharm documentation:

To move between tabs, press Cmd-Shift-] or Cmd-Shift-[.

Please do some research on your own before asking questions and, frankly, cluttering SO with bad questions. While this question might be helpful for certain people, a simple google search would yield better results.
